# New tab under a child window in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two different applications server A and B, there's a link in the window of A, who opens a new window of B.

My request now is: in the second click on A, I want to open a new tab in the window of B. An example of what I did:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try on</button>
<script>
  var myWindow;
 function myFunction() {    
  if(!myWindow) {
myWindow=window.open('https://google.com',"","width=500,height=500,toolbar=yes,resizable=1");
myWindow.focus();
 } 
 else {
   myWindow=myWindow.open('https://google.com',"_blank");
}
</script>
```

In the first click the window appears and opens google but in the second click that's not working.

Can you help xD

If it's duplicate question please give me the link :)

Comment: It's a permission issue. You can't do that.

Comment: there's any proposition ?

Comment: Why are you trying to open two cross domain `window`s?

Comment: I try to open another domain 2 from the first domain, for example the second domain shows informations about the page where I am in the first domain. And that's working when I click in first time, but After I have no control over the page where the second domain.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not possible, the opened `window` does not have the same origin as `window.opener`

Comment: So there's no solution ?

Comment: @JawadMINKHAR No, you are not in control of the domain 'https://*oogle.com', which has a different origin from `window.opener`